# Is there a standarized collection of mathematical definitions, theorems and lemmas?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, learning

I'm reading a book on abstract algebra and although it's good to read the proofs, I keep wishing there was a summary of the book without the proofs, so that I can consult it when needed. I think that if it is a good idea for this book, then it may be a good idea for all the mathematical subjects and if it is such a good idea, then it probably already exists.

Ideally, each definition would have links to the definitions on which it depends.

Comment: http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/aaol/theorems.html, http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/abstract_algebra/study_guide/contents.html

Comment: Mandatory shoutout to the Stacks Project, though it's at a much, much higher level than you're looking for. http://stacks.math.columbia.edu

Comment: @Moo Very nice! already I'm finding some differences with the book I'm reading. For example, Proposition 3.2.2 (ii) is redundant, which is why it is not included on the book I'm reading (the existence of a^-1 for every a implies the existence of e.)

Comment: @PatrickStevens exactly what I was looking for! But I can't even find the definition of a subgroup...

Comment: Indeed, the Stacks Project is not an introduction to anything :P